# How to Display ajax responseText?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Hi friends How do I get only the main message here is to show my j44?

```
error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
alert(xhr.responseText);
}
```

[image]

Comment: xhr.responseText.category[0]

Comment: @Niklesh — That will throw an exception. `xhr.responseText.category` is `undefined`, you can't access `[0]` of `undefined`.

Comment: Were you able to get the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make it

```
error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
   alert(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).category[0]);
}
```

Comment: That will throw an exception. `xhr.responseText.category` is `undefined`, you can't access `[0]` of `undefined`.